# Получение значения в hashmap, сравнение на уникальность и подсчет количества совпадений

Tags: java

в hashmap есть десять записей по принципу «Фамилия» - «Имя». Проверить сколько людей имеют совпадающие с заданным имя. и отследить количество совпадений.

Не понимаю что попадает в параметр String name метода getCountTheSameFirstName и как сравнивается name с tmp. Почему эти значения могут быть равны, какое значение у name изначально, оно ведь не изменяется? почему с ним все сравнивается? чего-то я не понимаю.

```
public class Solution
{
public static HashMap<String, String> createMap()
{
//Напишите тут ваш код
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("A", "Oleg");
map.put("B", "Sasha");
map.put("C", "Andrey");
map.put("D", "Kolya");
map.put("E", "Vasya");
map.put("F", "Petya");
map.put("G", "Andrey");
map.put("H", "Oleg");
map.put("I", "Sasha");
map.put("J", "Andrey");
return map;
}
public static int getCountTheSameFirstName(HashMap<String, String> map,     String name)
{
//Напишите тут ваш код
int count = 0;
for (String tmp : map.values())
{
    if(name.equals(tmp))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
}
```

Comment: Всё просто. В `name` передаётся имя. Вот пример http://ideone.com/mNY5Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот метод очевидно где-то вызывается и при вызове, в него передаётся два параметра, первый это `HashMap<String, String> map` видимо та `Map`, которую вы создаёте в первом методе и второй параметр это `name`. Судя по условиям задачи, это то самое имя, количество совпадений с которым вам надо найти.

```
int count = 0; // создаём и инициализиуем переменную, которой будем считать совпадения
```

это [for each loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) для которого вызывается метод [Map.values()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--):

```
for (String tmp : map.values()) 
{
    if(name.equals(tmp)) // проверяется, что имя из совпадает с одним из имею из map
    {
        count++; // увеличиваем значение
    }
}
return count; // возвращаем сколько насчитали
```

Надеюсь теперь вам всё понятно, если что-то еще не ясно, можете задать вопрос в комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно скопировать в `TreeMap<String, String>` что отсортирует значения имени так, что все совпадения будут рядом. Тогда, в цикле, можно сравнивать текущее и следующее значения на совпадения, что даст возможность пройтись по всему списку имен только одни раз для выявления общего числа совпадений...